# Error while listing directories recursively on C:\ drive

Tags: powershell, csv, directoryservices

I’m trying to list every file, including dll, exe, driver list, etc on my windows system using PowerShell.

The following gives me list of *only* the particular folder called "Users"

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName,Name |Where { $_.DirectoryName -ne $NULL } | Export-CSV C:\Filelist.csv
```

It gives the list of files in only Users folder and I get error when I try to list all files under `C` Drive using the following command as per my aim:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName,Name | Where { $_.DirectoryName -ne $NULL } | Export-CSV C:\Filelist.csv
```

I receive this error:

```
ERROR : Get-ChildItem : Access to the path ‘C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6’ is denied.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-Childitem <<<< C:\ -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName,Name | Where { $_.DirectoryName -ne $NULL } | Export-CSV C:\Filelist.csv
    + CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How do I list the *entire* `C` drive or all files including dll, scripts, exe s on my system and export to a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute your script as *admin*. Also you can *omit the error message* for files you don't have access to using the `-ErrorAction` common parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select-Object DirectoryName,Name |
    Where { $_.DirectoryName -ne $NULL } | 
    Export-CSV C:\Filelist.csv
```

Comment: Thank you much for this Martin! Lifesaving to me! :) I need to fetch the details, like file version and product version, last modified, those listed in file properties in the same CSV, is that possible, maybe through a different command???

Comment: Why did you removed the accepted answer? If you have another question, you should start one.

Comment: no, it was just a mistake, my bad, just wanted to edit the post @martin :)